# Problems with python regex encoding?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, encoding

I have a large `.txt` file that is made up of: `word1`, `word2`, `id`, `number` as follows:

```
s = '''
Vaya ir VMM03S0 0.427083
mañanita mañana RG 0.796611
, , Fc 1
buscando buscar VMG0000 1
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
lavadora lavadora NCFS000 0.414738
con con SPS00 1
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
sorprender sorprender VMN0000 1
a a SPS00 0.996023
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
persona persona NCFS000 0.98773
muy muy RG 1
especiales especial AQ0CS0 1
para para SPS00 0.999103
nosotros nosotros PP1MP000 1
, , Fc 1
y y CC 0.999962
la lo PP3FSA00 0.0277039
encontramos encontrar VMIP1P0 0.65
. . Fp 1

Pero pero CC 0.999764
vamos ir VMIP1P0 0.655914
a a SPS00 0.996023
lo el DA0NS0 0.457533
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
interesa interesar VMIP3S0 0.994868
LO_QUE_INTERESA_La lo_que_interesa_la NP00000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
clasificación clasificación NCFS000 1
A+ a+ NP00000 1
, , Fc 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
las el DA0FP0 0.970954
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
ahorran ahorrar VMIP3P0 1
energía energía NCFS000 1
, , Fc 1
si si CS 0.99954
no no RN 0.998134
me me PP1CS000 0.89124
equivoco equivocar VMIP1S0 1
. . Fp 1

Lava lavar VMIP3S0 0.397388
hasta hasta SPS00 0.957698
7 7 Z 1
kg kilogramo NCMN000 1
, , Fc 1
no no RN 0.998134
está estar VAIP3S0 0.999201
nada nada RG 0.135196
mal mal RG 0.497537
, , Fc 1
se se P00CN000 0.465639
le le PP3CSD00 1
veía ver VMII3S0 0.62272
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
gran gran AQ0CS0 1
tambor tambor NCMS000 1
( ( Fpa 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
acero acero NCMS000 0.973481
inoxidable inoxidable AQ0CS0 1
) ) Fpt 1
y y CC 0.999962
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
consumo consumo NCMS000 0.948927
máximo máximo AQ0MS0 0.986111
de de SPS00 0.999984
49 49 Z 1
litros litro NCMP000 1
Mandos mandos NP00000 1
intuitivos intuitivo AQ0MP0 1
, , Fc 1
todo todo PI0MS000 0.43165
muy muy RG 1
bien bien RG 0.902728
explicado explicar VMP00SM 1
, , Fc 1
nada nada PI0CS000 0.850279
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
ver ver VMN0000 0.997382
con con SPS00 1
hola RG 0.90937838
como VMP00SM 1
estas AQ089FG 0.90839
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
lavadora lavadora NCFS000 0.414738
de de SPS00 0.999984
casa casa NCFS000 0.979058
de de SPS00 0.999984
mis mi DP1CPS 0.995868
padres padre NCMP000 1
Además además NP00000 1
también también RG 1
seca seco AQ0FS0 0.45723
preciadas preciar VMP00PF 1
. . Fp 1'''
```

For example for the `s` "file" I would like to extract the `ids` that start with `AQ` and `RG` followed by their `word2`, but they must ocurre **one after the other** for the above example **this words hold the one after another order**:

```
muy muy RG 1
especial especial AQ0CS0 1
```

For **example this words doesnt hold the one after another order**, so I would not like to extract them in a tuple:

```
hola RG 0.90937838
como VMP00SM 1
estas AQ089FG 0.90839
```

I would like to create a regex that extract in a tuple list only the `word2` followed by its `id` like this: `[('word2','id')]` for all the .txt file and for all the words that hold true the one after another order. **For the above example this is the only valid output:**

```
muy muy RG 1
especiales especial AQ0CS0 1
```

and

```
también también RG 1
seca seco AQ0FS0 0.45723
```

Then return them in a tuple with its full `id`, since they preserve the one after another order:

```
[('muy', 'RG', 'especial', 'AQ0CS0'), ('también', 'RG', 'seco', 'AQ0FS0')]
```

I tried the following:

in:

```
t = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*(RG)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*?(\w+)\s*(AQ\w*)', s)
print t
```

**But my output is wrong, since it is droping the accent and some characters:**

out:

```
[('muy', 'RG', 'especial', 'AQ0CS0'), ('n', 'RG', 'seco', 'AQ0FS0')]
```

instead of, which is the correct:

```
[('muy', 'RG', 'especial', 'AQ0CS0'), ('también', 'RG', 'seco', 'AQ0FS0')]
```

Could someone help me to understand what happened with my above example and how to fix it in order to catch the `word2` and `id`that preserve the one after another ocurrence?. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Is ```mañanita mañana RG 0.796611``` valid?

Comment: Thanks for the help @wwii. Is not valid since there is no `AQ`  after `mañanita mañana RG 0.796611`

Comment: The only valid output for this is: `[('muy', 'RG', 'especial', 'AQ0CS0'), ('también', 'RG', 'seco', 'AQ0FS0')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, with the 8-bit strings (`str`), `\w` matches `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`. However if your use `unicode` and compile your pattern with `re.UNICODE` flag, then `\w` matches the word characters based on the unicode database.
[Python documentation 7.2.1 regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> When the `LOCALE` and `UNICODE` flags are **not specified**, matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. With `LOCALE`, it will match the set `[0-9_]` plus whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current locale. If `UNICODE` is set, this will match the characters `[0-9_]` **plus whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database**.

---

Thus you can do

```
u = s.decode('UTF-8')  # or whatever encoding is in your text file
t = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*(RG)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*?(\w+)\s*(AQ\w*)', re.UNICODE)
```

---

In Python 3 much of the `str`/`unicode` confusion is gone; when you open a file in text mode and read its contents, you will get a Python 3 `str` object that handles everything as Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that \w+ don't recognize special char é.

so if your txt is strictly split by space, you can replace \w with \S

the regex will be

```
t = re.findall(r'(\S+)\s*(RG)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*?(\S+)\s*(AQ\S*)', s)
```